# atomicMatch for Opensea via etherscan?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, contract, etherscan, opensea

Is it possible to complete an atomicMatch on Opensea via Etherscan?

Rinkeby as example
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x5206e78b21ce315ce284fb24cf05e0585a93b1d9#code

Some of the argument inputs look like they are taking several arguments as one?
For example it's asking for "feeMethodsSidesKindsHowToCalls (uint8[8])" but this is feeMethods, Sides, Kinds, how would you format that?

I understand you can do this via the JS SDK and not need to put in the arguments in this same way, but I can't get an API to test anything, OS are not responding to the request, which I gather is a common problem to have, and their generic test key on their docs won't allow input of additional arguments. Talk about making things hard for us.

Comment: I have the same question, were you able to crack it? If yes, please do share steps.